# How would you hide yourself whilst conducting a scan on a target network to identify open service ports?

Tags: network, proxy, ports, tcp, scan

I am working on this question which asks how you would conduct a scan of a target network to identify open service ports without revealing your IP address. It wants details such as IP address obfuscation, requirements to be met to receive stateful information and communication flows involved.

As I was confused, I answered this question in different ways:

1. A normal SYN ACK scan where the malicious actor would send a SYN/ACK to a proxy server, in which the proxy server relays it to the target network, this would obfuscate the malicious actor's IP address whilst giving them "stateful" information. Stateful, I interpret to mean the "entire information" about the ports on a target.
2. A half open scan, learned from NMAP's TCP SYN scan, where SYN packets are sent but never completed so that it does not get traced back to the sender. This still goes on through a proxy server.

I'm just so confused with the details and would appreciate some guidance on what would be right, wrong or where I've gone wrong anyway.

Comment: I'm not sure how the details of the SYN flags is relevant. All you've said is "use a proxy", which is one way to hide the scanner IP.

Comment: Then to get stateful information, is my answer in number 1 correct?

Comment: But, how is that relevant to the question? You don't want "stateful" info. You want to know what ports are open. You don't need "stateful" info. If you want to grab the banner, then you need to complete the handshake. But this is all besides what the question asks.

Comment: So then what would stateful information be? The summary question I gave says "requirements to be met, which is to receive stateful information"

Comment: That's a very ambiguous statement. If you use TCP, then you will get "stateful" information. But knowing the "state" of the port would also be "stateful". Either way, setting the SYN flags is not "stateful" information. There might be a language barrier, or you might need to ask the instructor what is actually required.

Comment: With the way the question was asked, I was confused by what exactly it meant but I see now. Thank you for the assistance!